# Jmeter Dynamic parallel graphql requests

Tags: jmeter

In perf tests, I have the below scenario.

1. the first graphql call fetches multiple account numbers
2. Next, multiple graphql calls are triggered in parallel - one for each account number in the above response. URL is the same, but the request body has different account numbers.

I added a JSR223 postprocessor for the first request and read account numbers into a list (added them to vars). I can read the list in JSR223 sampler but I cannot find how to use the list to make parallel graphql calls.

The number of parallel graphql calls is equal to the size of the list. The url of requests is the same, the account number in the payload needs to be different.

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of using [Parallel Sampler](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-sampler), you can dynamically add children (HTTP requests to execute) using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) like:

```
1.upto(vars.get('var_matchNr') as int, { index ->
    sampler.addURL(vars.get('var_' + index))
})
```

make sure that your `var_1`, `var_2`, etc. variables contain the full URL with the parameters

Parallel Sampler and Controller are not the part of official JMeter distribution, they need to be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

More information: [How to Use the Parallel Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/parallel-controller-in-jmeter)